# Darle eventos a un checkbox

Tags: javascript, eventos

yo tengo un checkbox y quiero que al activarlo el fondo del `<body>` cambie de color, como un toggle de modo nocturno.

```js
var toggle = document.querySelector(".onoffswitch-checkbox");
var body = document.querySelector("body");

toggle.addEventListener('checked', function() {
  body.style.background = "#2E2E2E";
});
```

Esto no funciona, y el error dice que no le puedo agregar un evento a un null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asegurate de que el código se ejecuta después de que la página termina de cargar el html; El evento no es `checked` si no `change`

```js
var toggle = document.querySelector(".onoffswitch-checkbox");
var body = document.querySelector("body");

toggle.addEventListener('change', function() {
  body.style.background = this.checked ? "#2E2E2E" : "initial";
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox">
```

Answer (score 4):

prueba cambiando el selector del checkbox:

```
    var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=checkbox]");
    checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        // Checkbox is checked..
    } else {
        // Checkbox is not checked..
    }
});
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Prueba dandole el evento con el script que te muestro a continuación; le das el evento en el `input` con el nombre que le tenga  -en este ejemplo yo le puse `name=checkbox` - , pero tienes que ponerle el nombre de tu check.

Ejemplo:

```js
      
 var eventcheck = document.querySelector("input[name=checkbox]");
    eventcheck.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        alert("Checkbox is  checked");
        document.body.style.background = "#669B9B";
    } else {
        alert("Checkbox is not checked");
        document.body.style.background = ""; 
    } });
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
```

con la linea de `document.body.style.background = "#669B9B";` 
se cambia el color del evento al darle check y al desmarcar tambien de la misma manera, en este caso use el codigo del color `#669B9B` para que vieras que puedes poner cualquier gama de colores usando el formato `#669B9B` 
espero que sea de tu ayuda y si esta pregunta te hizo entender mejor y te sirvio.

Comment: las respuestas que son solo códigos se consideran de baja calidad, por favor revisa [answer], es necesario lo expliques, mientras -1

Answer (score 2):

Para hacer lo que quieres debes acceder al `CheckBox` con el que deseas cambiar el fondo del cuerpo de la página.

Debes acceder al evento que se genera al hacer `click` a ese control:

```
document.querySelector(".onoffswitch-checkbox").addEventListener('change', (event) => {

})
```

Dentro de ese evento agregas las condicionales para cuando esta o no esta en `Checked` el `CheckBox`:

```
if (event.target.checked) {

} else {

}
```

Y para cambiar el color simplemente debes acceder de esta manera:

```
document.body.style.background = "#2E2E2E";
```

Aquí te muestro un ejemplo completo de como quedaría:

```js
document.querySelector(".onoffswitch-checkbox").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    document.body.style.background = "#2E2E2E";
  } else {
    document.body.style.background = "";
  }
})
```

```html
<body>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox"> Cambiar color
  </label>
</body>
```